# How to get the column index in which radio button has selected in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

Hi I want to know the column index which radio button  has selected in data table.

Here is my code for data table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
table=$('#ReportTable').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "ajax" :{
        url: 'ajax_call.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action:'loadEmailData'
        }   
    },
    "columnDefs": [ 
                    {  "aTargets": [0],
                         "mRender": function(data, type, full)
                         {
                             id=full[3];
                             var returnval = "<td><input type='radio' name='chkNew"+id+"'  class='call-checkbox' value="+id+"  id=\"chkNew'"+id+"'\" /></td>";
                               return returnval;
                         }

                     },
                     {  "aTargets": [1],
                         "mRender": function(data, type, full)
                         {
                             id=full[3];
                             var returnval = "<td><input type='radio' name='chkNew"+id+"'   class='call-checkbox'  value="+id+"  id=\"chkSubmit'"+id+"'\" /></td>";
                               return returnval;
                         }

                     },
                     {  "aTargets": [2],
                         "mRender": function(data, type, full)
                         {
                             id=full[3];
                             var returnval = "<td><input type='radio' name='chkNew"+id+"' class='call-checkbox' value="+id+" id=\"chkDeploy'"+id+"'\"/></td>";
                             return returnval;
                         }

                     }

                  ]
   });

  });
```

Here is function to get the selected coulmn index and id of selected column: Here it is alert the index of column like 0,1.  If I clicked 1st and  3rd column also it is alert as 0,1,It should alert 0,2

```
  var oTable = $('#ReportTable').dataTable();
  var rowcollection =  oTable.$('input[type="radio"]:checked', {"page": "all"});
  rowcollection.each(function(index,elem){
  var checkbox_value = $(elem).val();

     arr[index]=checkbox_value;
     alert(index);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var oTable = $('#ReportTable').dataTable();
  $("input:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function(){
      var tdColumn = $(this).closest("td");
      rowId= $(this).val();
      columnIndex= tdColumn.index();
      alert(columnIndex);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

That is becuase you are only iterating over checked radio button. Use:

```
rowcollection.each(function(index,elem){
var checkbox_value = $(elem).val();
   var globalindex = $(this).closest('tr')find('input[type="radio"]').index(this);
   arr[globalindex]=checkbox_value;
   alert(globalindex);
});
```

Comment: I want column index whether that selected radio button from 1st or 3rd column.

Comment: Yes I tried, It is displaying the count  of  column like 1,16,18

Comment: can you share the fiddle??

Comment: In every row either one of the radio button should be enabled, In this link it it enabling only one radio button in whole

Comment: That is a total different issue.

Comment: Please any one  tell me how to get the column index in which the radio button has selected